# Can't change a variable inside onSnapshot method

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, arrow-functions

So my intention is to fetch the data from Firestore with an onSnapshot method (as it automatically updates when a change occurs) and then write it inside a variable. I tried it with this:

```
let cityLocations;

onSnapshot(cityRef, (doc) => {
    cityLocations = doc.data().allCityLocations;
    console.log(cityLocations);
});
console.log(cityLocations);
```

(For debugging I had two console logs, inside and outside the arrow function)

But what ended up happening was, only the console.log() inside the arrow function wrote out the needed data.  The other console.log put out the still undefined value.
It also logged out the undefined value first.

Here is what the console wrote out:

```
undefined           app.js:63 
['3_3']             app.js:61
```

Line 61 being the first console.log and line 63 the second.

I tried to make a var inside the arrow function, but it didn't work either. In VSCode it said Local Var, which is really strange to me since var is supposed to bypass scope.
I'll be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: The second `console.log()` happens before the snapshot event, so the variable isn't updated yet.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use onSnapshot?  That's for realtime updates that happen over time. The function is asynchronous and returns immediately in all cases.  The callback function you provide will be invoked later every time the document changes.  If you want to get the document just once, use getDoc which returns a promise that you can use to get the vaue.

Comment: No, unfortunately I need the realtime updates. Thanks.

Comment: @Barmar According to the docs, the snapshot event is triggered at load as well. But if what you say is the case then what do you think I should do in order to use the data immediately after?

Comment: The only way you can use it *immediately* after is in the callback function. But you can also use it in other event listeners that run later.

Comment: For instance, add a button whose `click` listener logs the variable. When you click it, you should see the updated value.